# Local web page don't works into TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, google-maps-api-3, twebbrowser

I have a web page into my local PC and I need to show it into a TWebBrowser. It shows a heatmap like [this](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/layer-heatmap?hl=es).

When I show this page into IE, it is well displayed (it shows the heatmap), but when I load it into a TWebBrowser, it only display the map, not the heatmap. Why? Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: `TWebBrowser` is just a wrapper for Internet Explorer, so it should be behaving the same way that the full browser does.

Comment: Did you configure the machine to use modern browser in the control, or are you stuck with legacy browser

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know it, for this I don't understand why not work

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I use the default TWebBrowser

Comment: No. I mean the registry setting and doctype opt in that allows modern IE in TWebBrowser. Without this you get IE6 or some such.

Comment: @cadetill, David is hinting at the [Browser Emulation feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation). See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534614/twebbrowser-and-feature-browser-emulation-at-runtime) for more info...

Comment: thanks a lot, work perfectly now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TWebBrowser` is a wrapper of hosted `WebBrowser Control`. If your system has a MSIE 5-7 installed, your browser application renders web pages exactly the same as MSIE. I can imagine the heatmap looks broken in old MSIE, too.

If your system has a MSIE 8 (or higher) installed, your browser application will render web pages by default in compatible mode, unless you specify the default emulation mode explicitly in Registry.

**The Solution**

For instance, your system has MSIE 10 installed and your application is `yourapp.exe`. You'd write a string entry `name=yourapp.exe, value=10000` into Registry. *I recommend write to HKCU for the current user (not HKLM).*

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
                     yourapp.exe = (DWORD) 00010000
```

Now your application can render the heatmap exactly as MSIE10 does. A full list of emulation values is described at ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation)).

*Note that you should first read the version of MSIE installed on your system. You cannot set emulation mode to 11000 (MSIE11), if you have only MSIE10 installed.*

Comment: thanks a lot, work perfectly :)