# Delphi 7 Webbrowser - select without value

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need help...My problem is:

**Page source:**

```
<select name="year" id="year" class="form-control select-inline">
<option>1990</option>
<option>1991</option>
<option>1992</option>
<option>1193</option>
</select>
```

**In delphi 7, use:**

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.All.Item('year', 0).value := '1990';
```

**But form site continue in blank...Help me please**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TWebBrowser` is just a wrapper for the Internet Explorer ActiveX control, so this is really an IE DOM issue, not a Delphi issue.

Try setting the `select` element's `selectedIndex` property instead of its `value` property:

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.All.Item('year', 0).selectedIndex := 0;
```

The `value` property is what gets transmitted to the server, but only of there is an item selected to begin with.

Comment: Dont work bro, i try value := 0; and :=1990 and two method continue blank.

Comment: @AlexSilva as I said, DON'T set `value`, set `selectedIndex` instead. And clearly `1990` is not a valid index, your `select` only has indexes 0-3.

Comment: Ahh ok bro, work now thx <3

Comment: One ask about WebBrowser, I have IE 11 in my computer, but IE show in WebBrowser is version 7, why?

Comment: @AlexSilva because `TWebBrowser` runs in IE7 compatibility mode by default. See [How to have Delphi TWebbrowser component running in IE9 mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843845/), and [TWebBrowser and FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534614/), and other similar questions to enable other version modes.